# PHP login, getting wrong count value from query / fetch array

Tags: php

**EDIT**Thanks to the comments below it has been figured out that the problem lies with the md5, without everything works as it should.
But how do i implent the md5 then?

I am having some troubles with the following code below to login.
The database and register system are already working.
The problem lies that it does not find any result at all in the query.
IF the count is > 0 it should redirect the user to a secured page.
But this only works if i write count >= 0, but this should be > 0 , only if the user name and password is found he should be directed to the secure (startpage) of the site after login.
For example root (username) root (password) already exists but i cannot seem to properly login with it.

```
<?php
session_start();

if (!empty($_POST["send"]))
{   
$username = ($_POST["username"]);
$password = (md5($_POST["password"])); 
$count = 0;

$con = mysql_connect("localhost" , "root", "");

mysql_select_db("testdb", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT name, password FROM user WHERE name = '".$username."' AND password = '".$password."' ")
    or die("Error select statement");


$count = mysql_num_rows($result);


if($count > 0) // always goes the to else, only works with >=0 but then the data is not found in the database, hence incorrect
{
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

    $_SESSION["username"] = $row["name"];
    header("Location: StartPage.php");
}
else
{
    echo "Wrong login data, please try again";
}

mysql_close($con);    
}

?>
```

Comment: This sounds like your query is returning 0 rows. Echo your query and run it directly in phpMyAdmin or similar and see if a record is actually found

Comment: Obviously the data is not in the table. Have you tried printing out the username and password hash and comparing them to the ones in the table to make sure they match correctly?

Comment: *(reference)* http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: Try `joe' OR 'root'--` for `$username`

Comment: There is already proper data in the database. Already ran select statements trough SQLjog to check that.
root(username) root (password) is already included.

Comment: Sorry if this is overly obvious but I too can't find anything wrong with the script (except that it's not really injection-safe), but: did you check that the password stored in the db is actually the md5 hash of "root"?

Comment: This may be a stupid question but is the password in the database stored as a MD5 hash?

Comment: Doh its indeed the md5 that gives the problem, never thought of that.
I am still new to php, but how do i actually make sure the password has md5 algorithm on it then? Thanks a bunch!

Comment: When you look in the database, are passwords stored as plaintext, or are they a random set of letters?  If it's plaintext, obviously you don't need a hash.  If it's a random set of letters you know they did use a hash function.  Then the question becomes which one?  PHP has MD5, SHA1, and a few others.  I'd say you just look at the hash in the database for a known value, then display each hash from PHP and see which matches.

Comment: @Chris: PHP has a `md5()` function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php just do `md5($password)`

Comment: yes but if you look at my code it already has md5 before it, and does not work.

Comment: @Chris: I believe Felix is suggesting to not use PHP's md5, but to use your MySQL's md5. Change the query to [...]password = md5('".$password."') "[...] and remove the md5 function from PHP. Looking at your code now though, if the passwords stored in your database are actually md5, this SHOULD work as you have written it.
For debugging you could echo the php md5 of your user input and compare it by hand to what is in the database to see if they are matching up.
As noted previously, your code as it stands is very vulnerable to sql injection and you should look at mysql_real_escape_string.

Answer (score 2):

The best thing you can do in such situations is trying to find out where the problem lies.
So, you could proceed by steps and do the following:

1) start your script with a `print_r($_POST)`, to see what variables are passed by post (by absurd, the problem might even be related to the 'send' guard parameter you have ..IE a form being sent through get)

2) Assign your query to a variable (...and don't forget to escape parameters!) and print it to screen; and then exec it on mysql (or phpmyadmin) to see what results they give.

As a side note, as someone already pointed out, this code might be subject to SQL-injection, so you might consider using prepared statements; see here: [quick intro](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/356.cfm)

Answer (score 0):

Your login code is good.

But you also need to use md5() function BEFORE storing the password in the database. So when you are inserting the user record in the DB , apply the md5() to the password , save in the DB. Now when you will try to find the record on login, it will match correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You should rewrite this with mysqli or PDO and using a newer hash function as well as a salt. MD5 is very widely used and is a target for crackers.